Disabling only button that was clicked from querySelectorAll()
Currently trying to disable only a button that was clicked instead of all buttons that are in queryselectorall. I have been trying to figure this one out for a good while to no avail. Maybe I'm not wording my searches right or something, still pretty new to javascript so apologies.


let inc = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='incButton'");
let span = document.getElementById('countSpan');

// Enable buttons on page load
window.onload = function(){
        BtnsEnable();
    }

// Increase number
function IncCounter(){

    BtnsDisable();

    let count = span.innerHTML

    count++;
        span.innerHTML = count
        setTimeout(BtnsEnable,750);
}

// click    
inc.forEach(incButton => {
       incButton.addEventListener('click', IncCounter);
});

 // Enable and Disable functions
function BtnsEnable(){
    inc.forEach(incButton=> {
        incButton.disabled=false
    });
}
   
function BtnsDisable(){
    inc.forEach(incButton=> {
        incButton.disabled=true
    });
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
            <span id="countSpan">0</span>
            <br>
            <button id="incButton1" disabled>increase button1</button>
            <button id="incButton2" disabled>increase button2</button>
            <button id="incButton3" disabled>increase button3</button>
            <button id="incButton4" disabled>increase button4</button>
    </body>
</html>



jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skrrts/ouesy6f2/
I'm assuming it has to do with BtnsEnable and BtnsDisable functions being in a forEach loop, but that's the only way I can get the setTimeout to work and not sure what another solution is that works how I want it to work.
I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any help.

I think you can do like this;
https://jsfiddle.net/fxt2cmb3/
I changed just this place;
from..
inc.forEach(incButton => {
   incButton.addEventListener('click', IncCounter);
});

to...
inc.forEach(incButton => {
        incButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            inc = [incButton]; // incButton mean current clicked button
/* because we are calling 'IncCounter' function and IncCounter function is 
calling BtnsDisable function and BtnsDisable function is doing disable 
buttons inside to 'inc' array so if we assing current button to inc array 
this time  BtnsDisable function will do disable current clicked button
*/
            IncCounter();
        });
    });

